# Question about functions and variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Just wondering the difference in these 2 functions...

```
function getArea(width, height) {
  return width * height;
}




function getArea(width, height) {
  var area = width * height;
  return area;
}
```

I guess my question is, what is the point in the second example by storing the parameters in a variable?

Comment: "what is the point" ... there is none (in this case).

Comment: Generally, the reason to create a variable is to hold a value that will be needed more than one time. If it's a safe bet that that won't be the case, adding a variable just adds clutter. (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

The point to expanding your code this way would be for:

- Code Readability. It's clearer in the second example as to what's going on because the variable acts as documentation in a way.
- Debugging. In the 2nd example you can break on the return to see the value of area.
- Code Style - many devs prefer one or the other for their own style.

On the other side, the benefit of not doing this would be:

- The first example creates one less local variable, which is a smaller memory footprint.
- Smaller line count. Some devs care about line counts and short code, not my thing, but to some it matters.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Thanks for the side by side comparison and contrast!